# getProgress() is not working

Tags: android

I tried to get The value of the SeekBar but it is not working properly. here is the code :

```
            sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            sb.setMax(100);
            sb.setProgress(20);
            sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {

                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {


                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


                }

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    sb.setMax(100);
                    ShakeSilent.this.setTitle((sb.getMax()/sb.getProgress())*100);
                }
            });
```

Can anyone give me a proper reason?

Comment: May be you need to call setOnSeekBarChangeListener before setProgress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use arg0 instead of sb in the method:

```
ShakeSilent.this.setTitle((((float)arg0.getMax()/(float)arg0.getProgress()))*100);
```

Answer (score 0):

for example 100 / 50 is equals to 0.5, but because both values is int, result also converted to int, so 0.5 converted to int is 0, and 0 * 100 is 0.

You need cast it to double:

ShakeSilent.this.setTitle((sb.getMax()/(double)sb.getProgress())*100);

Comment: "100 / 50 is equals to 0.5", this made my day :)